# Passport.js authenticate issue with two simultaneous sessions : "Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client"

Tags: passport.js

I have issue with this code when testing using 2 simultaneous users (Playwright tests, using 2 workers) :

````
 passport.authenticate(strategy, {}, { failureRedirect: `/login`, state: redirect_url }), (err, user, info) => {
                    if (err || !user) {
                        return next(err || info);
                    }
                    req.logIn(user, err => {
                        if (err) {
                            return next(err);
                        }                      
                        if (loginpopup) {
                            return res.send(`
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        window.close();
                    </script >
                `);
                        }
                        else {
                            return res.redirect('/');
                        }
                    });
                })(req, res, next);```

I am receiving this error:
````

Error: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
...

```
From various posts on stackoverflow, I kind of understand that the issue come from the fact that I do a redirect inside the "authenticate" callback and that redirect interfer with passport's redirect. But I don't know how to solve this.

Could you please help me understand and fix this issue ?
Thanks you
```